# Node syntax in matrix not working - possibly due to new version of Beamer/pgf

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, tikz-matrix

I am recycling some material from an old beamer presentation, and I find
that code which used to compile just fine, no longer seems to work. I have replicated
the problem in the code below, which generates the error:

> ! Package pgf Error: No shape named A-1-1 is
>   known.

when I try to compile. It is particularly `\node[green]{1};` which causes the error.

It does - however - still compile on the system on which the presentation was originally
created, so I attribute the error to that system having earlier an installation of Beamer and/or PGF.

My main question is: Does this appear to be a reasonable explanation, and is there
an easy work-around?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}

 \matrix (A) [matrix of nodes, ampersand replacement=\&] at (0,0)
{%
\node[green]{1};  \&  1   \\ 
 1 \&  1   \\
};
\draw[green!50!black] (A-1-1) -- (A-2-1);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have matrix of nodes then you need `|[green]|1` in the (1,1) position. If any path command is left on the cell (tests whether the macro starts with a `\` is a path command) TikZ v3 doesn't bother with naming and numbering the node and parses whatever it finds.

Comment: Thanks. So no easy work-around for my original presentation I guess.